# Particle System по клику на экран

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть Canvas с расположенным на нем меню. Так же есть кнопка, по нажатию на которую в месте касания должны появляться брызги (GameObject с прикрепленным к нему PartcileSystem). 
 Я прикрепил к кнопке скрипт OnClickAnimationScript, по клику вызывается playAnimation

```
public void PlayAnimation()
    {
        Instantiate(effect, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Quaternion.identity);
    }
```

Вот, собственно, сам префаб объекта effect:[image: Префаб объекта effect]

Однако (внезапно) ничего не работает. Объект не виден в игре.
[image: Скриншот игры]

Хотя есть на сцене.
[image: Сцена]

Вроде бы я прикрепил CanvasRenderer, но это не помогло. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, убедитесь, что у вас все правильно сделано с точки зрения Sorting Layer и Order In Layer. То есть Order In Layer вашей Particle System должен быть приоритетней, чем у Canvas, либо вы можете создать отдельный Sorting Layer для вашей Particle System, таким образом, чтобы она рисовалась "над" Canvas.

Во-вторых посмотрите эту [ссылку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/700940/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-particle-sysme-%D0%B2-2%D0%94-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5), где решался похожий вопрос. Попробуйте технику описанную в ответе, то есть изменить настройки вашего Canvas на Screen Space Camera. Это очень важно потому что иначе, все элементы на сцене будут отрисовываться под Canvas. Подробней о режимах отрисовки Canvas можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UICanvas.html), там очень подробно все расписано.

Тажке могу посоветовать вам, не делать Instantiate при каждом клике, то есть не создавать объект каждый раз, потому что в Unity это довольно дорогая операция. Лучшим решением будет либо заранее создать на сцене 1 объект и менять его положение, каждый раз перезапуская систему частиц, либо, если вам нужно несколько одновременно играющих объектов, использовать такой прием как [Object Pooling](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling).